# How can i remove the dropdown option in country in checkout page in magento? I need to put only one country

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, onepage-checkout, drop-downs, option

From the following files :

> /app/design/frontend/base/default/template/customer/form/reg‌​ister.phtml
>   /app/design/frontend/base/default/template/customer/form/add‌​ress.phtml
>   /app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/‌​billing.phtml
>   and
>   /app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/‌​shipping.phtml

i did this trick converting php line

```
<?php echo $this->getCountryHtmlSelect() ?>
```

to html line

```
<select name="country_id" id="country" title="<?php echo $this->__('Country') ?>" class="validate-select">
    <option value="IN" selected="selected">India</option>
</select>
```

but not worked. In site showing one blank line and other line India.

I need only one line India or remove dropdown.

Comment: In which file did you make changes?

Comment: /app/design/frontend/base/default/template/customer/form/register.phtml
/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/customer/form/address.phtml
/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml and /app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/shipping.phtml

Comment: Which Magento version are you using?

Comment: go to admin panel > system > configuration > general > countries option > allowed countries.

Comment: i did by going admin panel process but not output changes.

Comment: Magento ver. 1.9.2.1

Answer (score 6):

Its very simple
system > configuration > general > countries option > allowed countries. Just select the country you want.
[image]

Comment: I did but still showing blank line and India in frontpage.

Comment: @ Dipak Kumar: That is how it appears in default magento after the above configurations are set. You'll have to add some JS and CSS to set the selected country option as India and hide the dropdown.

Comment: Tell me what code needs to add so that under Country Section only visible India and no drop down.

Comment: Then select Default country just above that. It'll work for you

Comment: not worked !!!!

Comment: Do you want to share your URL? May be i'll be able to help

Comment: http://www.shreehardwares.com/onestepcheckout/

Answer (score 1):

I think you are making changes to wrong files. Magento 1.9 comes with default `RWD` theme. So you will need to put your selectbox code in below files.

**app\design\frontend\rwd\default\template\persistent\checkout\onepage\billing.phtml**

```
<select name="billing[country_id]" id="billing:country_id" title="<?php echo $this->__('Country') ?>" class="validate-select">
    <option value="IN" selected="selected">India</option>
</select>
```

**app\design\frontend\rwd\default\template\checkout\onepage\shipping.phtml**

```
<select name="shipping[country_id]" id="shipping:country_id" title="<?php echo $this->__('Country') ?>" class="validate-select">
    <option value="IN" selected="selected">India</option>
</select>
```

**app\design\frontend\rwd\default\template\customer\address\edit.phtml**
**app\design\frontend\rwd\default\template\persistent\customer\form\register.phtml**

```
<select name="country_id" id="country" title="<?php echo $this->__('Country') ?>" class="validate-select">
    <option value="IN" selected="selected">India</option>
</select>
```

Comment: still showing blank line and other India under Country Section in magento?

Comment: Are you using any custom theme or third party checkout extension? Which browser you are using?

Comment: I am using chrome browser. 
Magento ver. 1.9.2.1

Comment: is there any theme you are using? or using Magento's default theme?

Comment: Magento default theme

Comment: Can you add a screenshot for your current dropdown to your question?

Comment: check this link http://www.shreehardwares.com/onestepcheckout/
under country section of shipping information

Comment: You are using a custom theme here. please enable template path hints from admin and check which phtml file it is using to display checkout page billing section, then update that file with above code

Comment: Under the Debug tab of the Developer, admin page showing only Profiler

Comment: You need to select store view to get template path hints option

Comment: yes i did, still not coming correct output

Comment: Can you show which file you edited and what code you added in the file?

Comment: after enabling template path hints -----

app\design\frontend\rwd\default\template\persistent\checkout\onepage\billing.phtml

remove this line-----
<?php echo $this->getCountryHtmlSelect('billing') ?>

added below line----
<select name="billing[country_id]" id="billing:country_id" title="<?php echo $this->__('Country') ?>" class="validate-select">
    <option value="IN" selected="selected">India</option>
</select>

Comment: Please refresh cache now if enabled. It should work.

Comment: not worked after Flush Cache Storage

Comment: Can you share screenshot of checkout page with template path enabled?

Comment: checkout page
http://www.shreehardwares.com/onestepcheckout/

Comment: Cant see any template path hints enabled

Comment: i did enable template path hints and Add Block Names to Hints

Comment: see that link, under country section there is one blank line and other line is India. See in inspect elements i need to remove <option value=""> </option>. So how to remove it ?